# Import from .backpack into existing database?

Tags: sql-server

I have ms sql server .backpack file from my cloud provider1 and can successfully import it to my local server to new db via databases -> Import Data-tier Application. OK, file is correct.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

When i try to import this file to another remote sql server (my cloud provider2) to existing database i've got an error:

> The database 'abc1234567' already exists on the target instance of SQL
>   Server. Specify a database name that does not already exist.

Both my providers have special webpanel to create database, so i can't specify non-existing database. :(

Neither SSMS, not [SqlPackage.exe Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#import-parameters-and-properties) allow me to use existing database. :(

Is there any way to import this backpack to existing database? (Maybe, 3rd party tools?)

Configuration:

- Provider1 has Server 2008 R2 RTM (db compability level = 100)
- Provider2 has Microsoft SQL Server 2016
- My local SSMS is from MS SQL 2017

The only way i see is restore to local db, allow xp_cmdshell then use bcp.exe in out

Comment: not for 2008, but related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174715/162702